# Rails: ensure that $.post from jQuery is received as format.json in Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller, response

I have a jQuery script that is trying to post data like so:

```
$.post({
    $('div#location_select').data('cities-path'),
    { location_string: $('input#city_name').val() },
});
```

This works, but for some reason the server receives it as an HTML request instead of a JS request. What gives? Here's the respond block in my controller:

```
if @city.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @city }
        format.json { render :json => @city, :status => :ok }
    end
else
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render :json => { :error => "Incorrect location format, please input a city and state or country, separated by a comma." }, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

How do you ensure that an Ajax request is hitting the Controller and being handled by the `format.js` responder?

---

**Update:** When I changed from `$.post` to `$.ajax` and specifically defined the data type it works:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $('div#location_select').data('cities-path'),
  data: { location_string: $('input#city_name').val() },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Is it because it's requesting JS not JSON and Rails is falling back to the default?

Comment: I tried both .js and .json and it made no difference.

Comment: It does work when I use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`, see update above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you passing the format through from the route in routes.rb?

```
"controller/action/(.:format)"
```

Comment: `$('div#location_select').data('cities-path')` is getting `cities_path` from Rails, passed through a data attribute in the view. So... I guess it may be posting to `/cities` and it should post to `/cities.json` ?

Comment: Just checked my code and I am using path.json so would say yes :)

Comment: Yep. That works too. I also could fix it by specifying `dataType` using the `$.ajax` function instead of `$.post` as shown in my update. But, this is simpler. Thanks!